# How to prevent c# UWP Scrollbar from minimizing

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp

The UWP scrollbar reduces in size when not in focus.

[image: Shows the small scrollbar when not in focus]

Here is the normal scrollbar with focus.

[image: Scrollbar with focus]

The listview..

```
 <ListView  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  
                   x:Name="emailListView"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,30,40,0"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Emails}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Tapped="ListView_Tapped"
```

ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                        CanDragItems="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        SelectionMode="Single" 
                        IsItemClickEnabled="True">

The real issue is with my hi-def laptop, the scrollbar does not enlarge on focus with the mouse. It is not a touch screen laptop, it is not set to tablet mode.

Ot is therefore impossible to scroll on the laptop

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `ScrollBar`'s style to make the `ScrollViewer` in the ListView' ControlTemplate to prevent Scrollbar from minimizing. You can get the default style for `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ScrollBar` in the (Program Files)(x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.xxxxx(SDK Version)\Generic folder.

Here is a simple style for your reqirement, you can put it on your `<Page.Resources/>`. In this style, I only modify the `VerticalThumb`'s CompositeTransform to ScaleX="1.0" and TranslateX="0" from the default style of `ScrollBar`.

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
   ...
    <Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb"
       Opacity="0"
       Grid.Row="2"
       Background="{ThemeResource ScrollBarPanningThumbBackground}"
       Template="{StaticResource VerticalThumbTemplate}"
       Width="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}"
       MinHeight="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}"
       AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
       RenderTransformOrigin="1,0.5">
        <Thumb.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="VerticalThumbTransform"
                            ScaleX="1.0"
                            ScaleY="1.0"
                            TranslateX="0"
                            TranslateY="0" />
        </Thumb.RenderTransform>
    </Thumb>
   ...
</Style>
```

Comment: This works, thanks, the scrollbar needs prettying up but I can do this. On my app it is only one scrollbar which causes the issue but this answer solves the main issue and the question is correctly answered.

Comment: Okay, glad to hear it helps and you solved the issue.

Comment: When I tried this it says, A value of type 'Thumb' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type SetterBaseCollection